# Reescritura de URL para diferentes secciones de la web

Tags: apache, .htaccess, url, redirección, reescritura-url

Con los enlaces internos a diferentes secciones de la web, cuando se hace click en uno, la url se transforma a www.web.com/#seccion-clickada

Me gustaría que mediante el fichero .htaccess, se pueda reescribir esa URL, convirtiendo esa url en www.web.com/sección-clickada

Y a su vez, que si se accede a la web mediante ella, te rediriga a donde realmente está el contenido que es www.web.com/#seccion-clickada

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No se puede, los #hashes no son interpretados por el servidor, solamente por el navegador.

Tu htaccess nunca va a poder acceder al hash.

La única solución que se me ocurre es que lo hagas a la inversa, con un lenguaje de navegador como JS

algo como esto:

```
if(window.location.hash) {
    let hash = window.location.hash.replace('#', '')
    window.location.replace('http://misitio.gar/'+hash)
}
```

Comment: Y luego hacer una redirección en htacces a la url con el hash no?

Comment: ¿Para que harías una redireccion de nuevo?

Comment: @memoadian en el supuesto caso de que alguien se haya familiarizado con la url modificada, y quiera acceder directamente a www.web.es/seccion y que realmente lo que esta haciendo es acceder a www.web.es/#seccion

Comment: En realidad tienes un mal enfoque, el hash comunmente se usa para acceder a los elementos de una web mediante anchors

Algunos frameworks como react o vue y quizás angular los usan para moverse entre diferentes rutas, teniendo la opción de aplicar un filtro de browserHistory que las convierte automáticamente de

mistio.dom/#hash a misitio.dom/hash

pero en este caso primero quieres una redireccion de hash a history y luego al revés lo cual lo haría un ciclo infinito

Ahora que escribo esto ¿no estás usando de casualidad react, Vue o angular?

Comment: @memoadian no no estoy usando ningún framework...

Comment: Ok, lo que intentas no tiene sentido imagina esto

Yo entro a mistio/#hash
el navegador me manda a misitio/hash
el server detecta el param y me manda a misitio/#hash
entonces el navegador detecta #hash y me manda misitio/hash

Se vuelve un ciclo infinito

O lo tienes como /hash o como /#hash para que convivas ambas debes duplicar el contenido.

Comment: @memoadian sí sí, lo entiendo. Solo buscaba que la url fuera mas amigable de cara al usuario. Gracias por la info

Comment: Y te entiendo y está bien, solo te comento que la doble redirección no es buena idea. Tu mismo te darás cuenta si la aplicas.